# android - XML-created and Code-created checkboxes are different

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I'm creating checkboxes in 2 diffent ways:

1) XML

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-10dp"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1" />
```

2) Java-code

```
 CheckBox myCheckBox = new CheckBox(this);
 myLayout.addView(myCheckBox);
```

And the look differently 
The one from code:

[image: code checked]
[image: code unchecked]

And from XML:

[image: xml checked]
[image: xml unchecked]

Why is that? 
And how can I make them equal?

Comment: Not sure why that happens exactly but you could try changing the background color for the checkbox by using a drawable

Comment: Forget what I said. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854047/how-to-change-the-color-of-a-checkbox and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26843098/android-appcompat-v721-0-0-change-material-checkbox-colors

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be because the XML version is newer whereas the Java version draws an older version of a checkbox from an older android. I would suggest just using either Java or Xml for both. Keep them the same

Comment: If I could do it with minimum pain, that would\ve already been the same.