# Change checkbox/radio button accent color

Tags: android, checkbox, android-studio, radio-button

I have an Activity with some radio buttons and checboxes. ATM they look like this:

[image]

Now i want to change this greenish accent color to something else. How would be the best way to achive that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26843098/android-appcompat-v721-0-0-change-material-checkbox-colors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `OnCheckedChangeListener` and one own image for this. For example:

```
checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {

            if (isChecked) {

                checkbox.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.yourImage);
            }

        }
    });
```

Use a one-color-image when you want a one-color-background like the green one.

Comment: How would i create this image?
And isnt this a bit complex to do it for every checkbox? isnt there a way to change that for all checboxes generally?

Answer (score 1):

create a `checkbox_selector.xml` in your `drawable` folder like this, and you need two image `normal_checkbox.png` and `selected_checkbox.png`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/normal_checkbox" 
          android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/selected_checkbox" 
          android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/normal_checkbox"/>    
</selector>
```

and now change your layout file where you declare CheckBox

```
<CheckBox
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:button="@drawable/checkbox_selector"
android:text="My CheckBox"
android:textColor="@color/Black" />
```

for more [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965484/custom-checkbox-image-android)

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for this in 2021 and after, now there's a simplier way to accomplish this, using just this little piece of css:

```
input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio] {
    accent-color: #FFCD00;
}
```