# Tint menu item checkbox

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat

How can I programmatically change the `CheckBox` color of my menu items? I'm using `AppCompat` and I could not find a way to that.

Actually, the main problem is that I can't extract the `CheckBox` from the menu.

Does anyone have an idea how this can be done?

Comment: See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26843098/android-appcompat-v721-0-0-change-material-checkbox-colors

Comment: This shows how to do it in xml via theme dependent colors, that's working fine of course. My theme does not know which color the user has selected, so I need to do it in code...

Answer (score 0):

The GreenMatter library may help you achieve the functionality you are looking for:

https://github.com/negusoft/GreenMatter